# Additional space purchase

Tags: gmail, google-one

After constantly receiving message on my Gmail that I am out of storage space and deleting anything and everything I can, I have finally caved in and purchased some extra space - except I am still getting the same message. If they block my emails I am in trouble. The payment has been confirmed and it is now weeks since I paid. Anyone have any information on how I can sort this out?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. This looks to be an issue that you should report to Google One support -> https://one.google.com/about/support.